# Django input forms not showing up in my template

Tags: python, html, django, web

My problem is that when I go to my add.html page the input forms for title and textarea do not show up. For context, this is for an online course where I have to design a "wiki". This section of code is for adding an entry (a title and body content)

Here is my code:

**views.py**

```
class Form(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label="Post Title")
    textarea = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(), label='')

def create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
            textarea = form.cleaned_data["textarea"]
            entries = util.list_entries()
            if title in entries:
                return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html")
            else:
                util.save_entry(title, textarea)
                page = util.get_entry(title)
                page_converted = markdowner.convert(page)

                context = dict(body=page_converted, title=title)

                return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", context)
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/create.html", {
            "post": Form()
        })
```

**add.html**

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
<h1>
    Add Post
</h1>
    <form action="{% url 'create' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h6 class="post-title">Title: {{ post.title }}</h6>
            {{ post.textarea }}
        <input type="submit" value="add entry">
    </form>
    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">View Entries</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use This :-

**add.html**

```
 {% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

 {% block body %}

<h2>Add Post</h2>
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
        {{ form.as_p }}
        </table>
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
</div>
<a href="{% url 'index' %}">View Entries</a>

{% endblock body %}
```

**views.py**

```
def create(request):

    if request.method != 'POST':

        form = Form()
    else:

        form = Form(data=request.POST)
        new_post = form.save(commit=False)
        new_post.owner = request.user
        new_post.save()
        return redirect('/') #put here, whatever and whenever you want to redirect.


    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'mains/create.html', context)
```

Comment: I used this, and the only thing that showed up, once again, was the submit button

Comment: nothing still, the code runs the same as. before without the input forms showing up in the template

Comment: @MattB, I have updated add.html in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Either use the Django forms or bootstrap|html forms please don't try to include both.
The problem here is that you shouldn't use

```
{{post.title}} -> {{post}} and remove {{post.textarea}}
```

For more info refer [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/)